# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error in Asynctask

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a project on steganography, in which after hiding the message in image, I want to send the image to wamp server in the pc. Following is the AsyncTask I have used to send an image to wamp server in which I'm getting the Fatal Exception:

```
private class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

Bitmap image;
String name;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList();

public UploadImage(String name){

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    path = path+"/stegimg1.png";
    Bitmap SendImg1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

    this.image = SendImg1;
    this.name = name;

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Constructor - UpImg",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


    HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVERADDRESS + "/SavePicture.php");

    try{
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
        client.execute(post);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null; 
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image sent to the server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside OnPreEXEC" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);



    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedImage));
    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    super.onPreExecute();

}
```

}

The Logcat output I'm getting is

```
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:365)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:228)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
05-17 16:45:39.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at com.msrohit.imageselect.MainActivity$UploadImage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:209)
```

What has gone wrong here??

Comment: `What has gone wrong here??` A very large image all loaded in memory

Comment: didn't get you....what needs to be changed here...?

Comment: In uploadimage... you are loading an image in memory. That image is simply too big.

Comment: Can you give me any hints....how to send that image to server??

Comment: Do I need to increase the memory of Emulator??

Comment: For instance, you could stream it. It's not adviceable, because it's like saying `can I increase the memory of my users devices?`. Instead, you can increase the heap size used by your app.

Comment: Thank you Bob.... You made my day..Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android sets a hard limit on the heap size for each app. The exact
>   heap size limit varies between devices based on how much RAM the
>   device has available overall. If your app has reached the heap
>   capacity and tries to allocate more memory, it will receive an
>   OutOfMemoryError.

You should **increase Heap Size and reduce Image Size** . Hope this helps .

Comment: Thank You @Amiya...I got that long back itself.